# EntityManager returning NULL in Seam3 using Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, persistence, jboss7.x, entitymanager, seam3

i need your help for correct configuration of my web app using Seam3 on jboss 7 with Hibernate 4.

When i try to inject EntityManager and use it, the entitymanager result NULL, but if try to get EntityManager by Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU").createEntityManager() the result is correct.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="accbetaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>accbeta</jta-data-source>
    <properties>               
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />            
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my EntityManagerProducer

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Produces
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}
}
```

This is my /Web-INF/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
<interceptors>
 <class>org.jboss.seam.faces.context.conversation.ConversationBoundaryInterceptor</class>
<class>org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
</beans>
```

and this is my class for test EntityManager...

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("first")
public class first implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1625566649081574918L;
private String testBenvenuto;

@Inject 
   private EntityManager entityManager;


public first() {
    this.testBenvenuto = "Welcome";
    starting();

}

public void starting(){
    this.testBenvenuto = this.testBenvenuto+" "+entityManager;
    this.testBenvenuto = this.testBenvenuto+" "+Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("accbetaPU").createEntityManager().toString();

}

public String getTestBenvenuto() {
    return testBenvenuto;
}

public void setTestBenvenuto(String testBenvenuto) {
    this.testBenvenuto = testBenvenuto;
}
}
```

When try to deploy(WAR) in JBOSS As7 the App are deployed without Exception...

After a few hours ..

I have tryed to use this code in EntityManagerProducer:

```
@ExtensionManaged
    @ConversationScoped
    @Produces
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="accbetaPU")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

but i have this error during deploy:

```
16:14:03,550 INFO [org.jboss.solder.core.CoreExtension] (MSC service thread 1-1) Preventing class org.jboss.seam.international.locale.LocaleConfiguration from being installed as bean due to @Veto annotation
16:14:05,715 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceUnit @ConversationScoped @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
 at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:96)
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_25]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_25]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceUnit @ConversationScoped @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.checkEEResource(EEResourceProducerField.java:133)
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.initialize(EEResourceProducerField.java:125)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:119)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:227)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:378)
 at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:81)
 at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:89)
 ... 5 more

16:14:05,715 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Service status report
 Services which failed to start:
 service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceUnit @ConversationScoped @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
```

WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceUnit @ConversationScoped @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped

What should I do? What's missing?

Here is a list of libraries in the war file:

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-0.9.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.CR1.jar
jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
joda-time-1.6.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
ocpsoft-pretty-time-1.0.6.jar
picketlink-idm-api-1.5.0.Alpha02.jar
picketlink-idm-common-1.5.0.Alpha02.jar
picketlink-idm-core-1.5.0.Alpha02.jar
picketlink-idm-spi-1.5.0.Alpha02.jar
postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
prettyfaces-jsf2-3.2.0.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.1.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.1.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.1.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
seam-faces-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-faces-api-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-international-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-international-api-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-persistence-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-persistence-api-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-security-3.1.0.Final.jar
seam-security-api-3.1.0.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
solder-api-3.1.0.Final.jar
solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar
solder-logging-3.1.0.Final.jar
```

The Jboss version is 7.0.2

Help me please

---

Thanks for your answer..
I have tried to remove `hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.CR1.jar` and `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`
but without effect!

I have also changed persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="accbetaPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/AccbetaDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate (default provider for JBoss AS) -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- Only format when you need to debug, because it slows things down -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When i try to create entity manager in this way...

```
@ExtensionManaged
    @ConversationScoped
    @Produces
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="accbetaPU")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

the error is the same....

```
17:11:20,589 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @ConversationScoped @PersistenceUnit @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
 at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:96)
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_25]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_25]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @ConversationScoped @PersistenceUnit @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.checkEEResource(EEResourceProducerField.java:133)
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.initialize(EEResourceProducerField.java:125)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:119)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:227)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:378)
 at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:81)
 at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:89)
 ... 5 more

17:11:20,605 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Service status report
 Services which failed to start:
 service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."accbeta.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @ConversationScoped @PersistenceUnit @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
```

---

Thanks for your answer..
I have tried to remove `hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.CR1.jar` and `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`
but without effect!

I have also changed persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="accbetaPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/AccbetaDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate (default provider for JBoss AS) -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- Only format when you need to debug, because it slows things down -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When i try to create entity manager the error is the same....

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing `hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.CR1.jar` and `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`. Not sure that's the issue here, but those aren't needed for sure.

Also, shouldn't the `<jta-data-source>accbeta</jta-data-source>` be something like `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/accbeta</jta-data-source>`? Admittedly I haven't used JPA enough yet in AS 7, but I know most of the examples look like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I read your stack trace, check if this little modification changes the stack trace.

In your EntityManagerFactory delete the @ConversationScope and add @Dependent annotation.

I mention that for:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001502 Resource producer field [Resource Producer Field [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceUnit @ConversationScoped @Produces startup.first.emf]] must be @Dependent scoped
```